# "Mixed content" Error when accessing HTTP within HTTPS page

Tags: javascript, ssl, iframe, mixed-content

Our intranet website has to communicate with a client .NET app. We're using a HttpListener (on http://localhost:[port]) on the client app and an iframe that refers to this url in the page. Its working like a charm when the page is HTTP.

Problem:
When the site is HTTPS a 'Mixed content' Javascript error is displayed in newer browsers and the request doesnt arrive at the client.

I believe this error would also occur when using an Ajax request instead of an iframe.

I also tried to bind a self-signed certificate to the listener and listening on https://localhost:[port] (which works for IE), but since the Firefox has its own certificate store its really tough to install it there automatically (IE uses Windows certificate store which is easy to install there).

So, does anyone know any possibility to make a request to http://localhost:[port] when the site itself is HTTPS that works for both FF and IE?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just run everything on https? Why do you have mixed content in the first place?

Comment: As I wrote: Its very ugly to automatically install a certificate into firefox (you need to use NSS tools and have C++ Redistributable 2010 installed)

Comment: Oh right, so `http://location:[port]` is not actually a website but the API for your .NET app? That's weird. Why not use XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: Yeah kind of. HttpListener is a .NET class that listens on incoming requests to some url:port, which in my case is http ://localhost:[port]. With that way, I can easily talk to my .NET app without installing some browser add-ins like ActiveX or something (like http ://localhost:[port]/?action=doStuff). Where should I use XMLHTTPRequest? On the page instead of the iframe? Wouldnt it also throw an mixed content error? Thank you

Comment: Ok you lost me again, why is the iframe there?

Comment: When accessing i.e. a html page that includes an iframe (<iframe src="http: //localhost:45910/?action=doSomething" />) the browser calls that url. And my client app listens to that url and receives the request then.

Comment: @Powerslave, do you use some server? or simple static html page?

Comment: The intranet site is ASP.NET hosted on IIS and the iframes are within *.aspx pages.

Comment: @Powerslave, so you can simple do request to intranet server and from it to your app with something like [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Nope, I have to do the request from the client browser to the client app. Every user can only talk to his own client via browser.

Comment: @Powerslave, so you have two way: do all _http_, or do all _https_

Comment: Yep. I think I'll stick it with that way that we use two listen urls (http + https) and when a user wants to use https and Firefox together he has to to import the certificate manually if they want to communicate with the client.

Answer (score 1):

Change the iframe to:

```
<script>
    var request = new XMLHTTPRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:[port]/?action=doStuff");
    request.send();
</script>
```

You will also need to make some minor modifications to your app.

It needs to implement an OPTIONS method and it needs to return a cross-origin-resource-policy. This sounds a lot harder than it is, it just needs to return a reply with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to `*`.

The response of the `GET` request must also have this header.

If you know all the domains that try to communicate with your app on localhost you can change the `*` to a whitelist or even just a single value.

Comment: mithinks this anyway would be blocked as mixed content, because request would be from _https_ to _http_

Comment: Yep, what Grundy says: Still occuring "mixed content" error. Request won't even arrive at my client.